# React некорректно обрабатывает состояния

Tags: reactjs

Сразу извиняюсь за огромный код, выкладываю его для полноты картины. Взял пример на Preact, который корректно исполнялся, хотел перевести его на React, но вышло, кажется, не совсем удачно. Когда пользователь вводит пароль/email, вызывается callback validData(), в нем обрабатывается ввод, к примеру, если пароль и его подтверждение не совпадают, уведомить пользователя. Но вместо сравнения паролей "В реальном времени" они проверяется только после ввода еще одного символа (и, соответственно, еще одного вызова коллбэка). Для примера, если я введу в поля паролей
12345 и 12345, то они не будут совпадать, но если я добавлю еще символ (12345 123456), то они якобы совпадут. Очевидно, React вместо сравнения в реальном времени проверяет прошлое состояние, как это исправить? Это моя первая попытка в React и я совершенно в нем не разбираюсь :(

```
const { createElement } = React;

//Рендер
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            registration: 0,
            password: '',
            repeatedPassword: '',
            feedback: 'Добро пожаловать!',
            valid: false,
            isWaiting: false
        };

        this.wrapper = React.createRef();
        this.email = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if ('alt' in window) {
            alt.on('error', errorName => {
                this.updateFeedback(errorName);
                this.setState({ isWaiting: false })
            });

            alt.on('success', successMessage => {
                this.updateFeedback(successMessage);
            });

            alt.on('setEmail', email => {
                this.setState({ email }),
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.email.current.value = this.state.email;
                }, 500);
            });

            alt.on('goToLogin', () => {
                this.setState({ registration: false, isWaiting: false });
            })

            setTimeout(() => {
                if ('alt' in window) {
                    alt.emit('ready');
                }
                this.email.current.focus();
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    updateFeedback(msg) {
        this.setState({ feedback: msg })
    }

    validData(e) {
        if (e.target.id === 'email') {
            this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
        }

        if (e.target.id === 'password') {
            this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
        }

        if (e.target.id === 'repeatedPassword') {
            this.setState({ repeatedPassword: e.target.value });
        }

        if (!this.checkEmail(this.state.email)) {
            this.setState({
                feedback: 'Введите корректную почту.', valid: false });
            return;
        }

        if (this.state.password.length <= 5 || this.state.password.length >= 16 ) {
            this.setState({
                feedback: 'Пароль должен быть от 5 до 16 символов!', valid: false});
            return;
        }

        if (this.state.registration && this.state.password !== this.state.repeatedPassword) {
            this.setState({
                feedback: 'Пароли не совпадают.', valid: false });
            return;
        }

        if (this.checkEmail(this.state.email)) {
            this.setState({ valid: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ valid: false });
        }

        this.setState({ feedback: 'Всё хорошо!' });


    }

    checkEmail(mail) {
        var reg = /.+@.+\..+/i;
        return reg.test(String(mail).toLowerCase());
    }

    submitData(){
        this.setState({ isWaiting: true });

        if ('alt' in window) {
            if (this.state.registration) {
                alt.emit('registerAccount', this.state.email, this.state.password)
            } else {
                alt.emit(
                    'existingAccount',
                    this.state.email,
                    this.state.password,
                    true
                );
            }
        }
    }

    setRegistration(){
        this.setState({ fadeOut: 1 });

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ registration: true, fadeOut: 0 })
        }, 1000);
    }

    setLogin(){
        this.setState({ fadeOut: 1 });

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ registration: false, fadeOut: 0 })
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return createElement(
            'div',
            {
                id: 'app',
                className: this.state.isWaiting
                    ? 'none animated fadeOut'
                    : 'regular animated fadeIn'
            },
            createElement('div', { className: 'header' }, createElement('div', { className: 'logo' }, 'Logo')),
            createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'animated flash container' },
                createElement('p', { className: 'center', id: 'feedback' }, this.state.feedback)
            ),
            createElement(
                'div',
                {
                    ref: this.wrapper,
                    className: this.state.fadeOut
                        ? 'animated fadeOut innerwrapper'
                        : 'animated fadeIn innerwrapper'
                },
                this.state.registration
                ? createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'container' },
                    createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'right' },
                        createElement(
                            'button',
                            { onClick: this.setLogin.bind(this) },
                            'Авторизация'
                        )
                    )
                )
                : createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'container' },
                    createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'right' },
                        createElement(
                            'button',
                            { onClick: this.setRegistration.bind(this) },
                            'Новый аккаунт?'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                //Email
                createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'container' },
                    createElement(
                        'div',
                        {
                            className: 'content'
                        },
                        createElement('p', {}, 'Почта'),
                        createElement('input', {
                            type: 'text',
                            name: 'email',
                            placeholder: 'Почтовый адрес',
                            autoComplete: 'off',
                            onChange: this.validData.bind(this),
                            id: 'email',
                            ref: this.email,
                            className: this.checkEmail ? 'green' : 'red'
                        })
                    )
                ),
                //Пароль
                createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'container' },
                    createElement(
                        'div',
                        {
                            className: 'content'
                        },
                        createElement('p', {}, 'Пароль'),
                        createElement('input', {
                            type: 'password',
                            name: 'password',
                            placeholder: 'Пароль',
                            onChange: this.validData.bind(this),
                            id: 'password',
                            className:
                                (this.state.registration &&
                                    (this.state.password.length >= 5 &&
                                        this.state.password.length <= 16 &&
                                        this.state.repeatedPassword.length >= 5 &&
                                        this.state.repeatedPassword.length <= 16 &&
                                        this.state.password === this.state.repeatedPassword)) ||
                                (!this.state.registration && this.state.password.length >= 5)
                                    ? 'green'
                                    : 'red'
                        })
                    )
                ),
                this.state.registration
                    ? createElement(
                        'div',
                        {
                            className: 'container'
                        },
                        createElement(
                            'div',
                            { className: 'content' },
                            createElement('p', {}, ''),
                            createElement('input', {
                                type: 'password',
                                name: 'password',
                                placeholder: 'Подтверждение пароля',
                                onChange: this.validData.bind(this),
                                id: 'repeatedPassword',
                                className:
                                    (this.state.registration &&
                                        (this.state.password.length >= 5 &&
                                            this.state.password.length <= 16 &&
                                            this.state.repeatedPassword.length >= 5 &&
                                            this.state.repeatedPassword.length <= 16 &&
                                            this.state.password === this.state.repeatedPassword)) ||
                                    (!this.state.registration && this.state.password.length >= 5)
                                        ? 'green'
                                        : 'red'
                            })
                        )
                    )
                    : createElement('div', { className: 'container' }),
                createElement(
                    'div',
                    {
                        className: 'container'
                    },
                    createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'center' },
                        createElement(
                            'button',
                            {
                                onClick: this.submitData.bind(this),
                                disabled: !this.state.valid,
                                className: this.state.valid ? 'green' : 'red'
                            },
                            'Отправить'
                        )
                    )
               )
            )
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(createElement(App), document.querySelector('#render'));
```

Comment: Фиддл для тестов кода выше: https://jsfiddle.net/Vynderman/s3ckgj4d/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод setState является асинхронным. Когда несколько setState выполняются в одной функции, то нет гарантии, что они выполнятся в нужном порядке и с актуальными данными.
Ну и не обязательно результат валидации записывать в стейт. Можно вычислять валидность "на ходу" прямо при рендеринге. Вот упрощенный пример:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      repeatedPassword: ''
    }
  }
  
  onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangePassword = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onRepeatPassword = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      repeatedPassword: e.target.value
    });
  }

  validateForm() {
    let valid = true;
    let feedback = 'Добро пожаловать!';
    
    if (!this.checkEmail(this.state.email)) {
      return {
        feedback: 'Введите корректную почту.', 
        valid: false 
      }
    }
    
    if (this.state.password.length < 5 || this.state.password.length > 16 ) {
      return {
        feedback: 'Пароль должен быть от 5 до 16 символов!', 
        valid: false
      }
    }
    
    if (this.state.password !== this.state.repeatedPassword) {
      return {
        feedback: 'Пароли не совпадают.', 
        valid: false 
      }
    }
    
    return {
      feedback: 'Добро пожаловать!',
      valid: true
    }
  }

  checkEmail(mail) {
    var reg = /.+@.+\..+/i;
    return reg.test(String(mail).toLowerCase());
  }
    
  render() {
    let {feedback, valid} = this.validateForm();
    
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input 
            type="email" 
            className="form-control" 
            id="exampleInputEmail1" 
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
            value={this.state.email}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            className="form-control" 
            id="exampleInputPassword1" 
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={this.onChangePassword}
            value={this.state.password}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword2">Password 2</label>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            className="form-control" 
            id="exampleInputPassword2" 
            placeholder="Password 2"
            onChange={this.onRepeatPassword}
            value={this.state.repeatedPassword}
          />
        </div>
        {valid && 
          <div className="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {feedback}
          </div>
        }
        
        {!valid && 
          <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {feedback}
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Всё дело в том, что метод `setState()` добавляет в очередь изменения в состоянии компонента. Фактически, метод `setState()` не всегда обновляет компонент сразу. Он может группировать или откладывать обновление до следующего раза. Это делает чтение `this.state` сразу после вызова `setState()` потенциальной ловушкой. Отсюда и проблема того, что фактически у Вас одинаковые значения, а согласно состоянию - разные.

Так как приведенному выше коду далеко до совершенства, я предложу в качестве альтернативного решения небольшой хак. Первым делом добавим в метод `validData` в самое начало две переменные:

```
let password = this.state.password;
let repeatedPassword = this.state.password;
```

Здесь мы берем значение из стейта и сохраняем в переменную. Пока всё просто. Далее, дополним две проверки новыми присваиваниями:

```
if (e.target.id === 'password') {
  this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
  password = e.target.value;
}

if (e.target.id === 'repeatedPassword') {
  this.setState({ repeatedPassword: e.target.value });
  repeatedPassword = e.target.value;
}
```

Данный код гарантирует нам, что в переменных `password` и `repeatedPassword` будет актуальное значение. Далее изменим код проверки, будем сравнивать не значения из стейта, а значения из переменных:

```
if (this.state.registration && password !== repeatedPassword) {
  this.setState({
     feedback: 'Пароли не совпадают.',
     valid: false,
  });

  return;
}
```

И после этого странное поведение уйдет, и Вы увидите заветную надпись *"Всё хорошо!"* на форме своего приложения. Настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией: [**`setState()`**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)